# Swift: 'Authorization to share the following types is disallowed: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime'

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am trying to use healthkit roughly following this tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started) but requiring a different HKQuantityTypeIdentifier. Code in HealthKitManager class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class HealthKitManager {

let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((_ success:Bool, _ error:NSError?) -> Void)!)
{


    let healthKitTypesToWrite: Set<HKSampleType> = [
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.appleExerciseTime)!
    ]
    let healthKitTypesToRead: Set<HKObjectType> = [
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.appleExerciseTime)!
    ]


    // If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
    {
        let error = NSError(domain: "com.example", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"HealthKit is not available in this Device"])
        if( completion != nil )
        {
            completion?(false, error)

        }
        return;
    }
    healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypesToWrite, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in

        completion?(success, error! as NSError)
    }

}
```

}

and in the ViewController trying to call healthKit:

```
let healthManager:HealthKitManager = HealthKitManager()


func authorizeHealthKit() {
    print("1")
    healthManager.authorizeHealthKit { (authorized,  error) -> Void in
        if authorized {
            print("HealthKit authorization received.")
        }
        else
        {
            print("HealthKit authorization denied!")
            if error != nil {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when calling authorizeHealthKit I am getting the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Authorization to share the following types is disallowed: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime'. The print "1" statement is called before the crash.

Answer (score 4):

Your app is not allowed request authorization to write `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.appleExerciseTime` since the definition of that type is proprietary to Apple. You should remove that `HKQuantityType` from `healthKitTypesToWrite`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought this might be the case but could not see any documentation to support it. So there is no way to record or add to appleExerciseTime using healthKit? If not then do you know how can you record a user workout?